# Fragment in activity not showing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a ListView inside an activity. But when I run the app, the ListView is not showing, but instead just shows me a blank activity. What is the problem?
These are the files:

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

ListFragment.java:

```
    public class ListFragment extends Fragment{
    ListView list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        list = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));
        return list;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment class="com.dandvrn.ListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

list_fragment.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: MainActivity doesn't start your fragment.

Comment: Why not? Isn't it enough to inflate the layout?

Comment: And to anyone that downvotes, please explain why.

Comment: You're just inflating the layout, not calling the Fragment itself. So you just show a blank listview with no adapters, thus, shows nothing.

Comment: In your MainActivity.java, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 2):

your giving `android:layout_width="0dp"` to the fragment in your xml, try to give a size > 0

Comment: Tried that. Changed nothing.

Comment: @DanDv ok then, please update the question because with 0dp it is supposed to show nothing, another thing you could do is to log something in your fragment onCreateView to see if the fragment is created

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes:

1) You have to set your activity's content view as the layout of your activity and not the fragment's layout:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

2) `onCreateView` should return your fragment's view. Also, do as following to correctly access your ListView:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
ListView list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));
    return v;
}
```

Hope it will help you! :-)